# Merge data in Excel to multiple Word documents

Tags: vba, excel, ms-word

I would need some help from you to complete this VBA I have. What should I do with it if I would want the text to stay the same like it was in the excel file where it had different fonts, sizes and colors? And how should i edit the VBA to make it jump a extra row before pasting the data?

For example:

**ITEM ID:** *551555*

**IN STOCK:** *14*

Instead of

ITEM ID: 551555
IN STOCK: 14

```
Sub Copy2Word()
Const lngHeaderRow = 1
Const lngFirstRow = 2
Dim lngLastRow As Long
Dim lngRow As Long
Const lngFirstCol = 1
Dim lngLastCol As Long
Dim lngCol As Long
Dim objWord As Object
Dim objDoc As Object
Dim objRng As Object
On Error Resume Next
Set objWord = GetObject(Class:="Word.Application")
If objWord Is Nothing Then
    Set objWord = CreateObject(Class:="Word.Application")
    If objWord Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "Cannot start Word!", vbExclamation
        Exit Sub
    End If
End If
On Error GoTo 0
objWord.ScreenUpdating = False
Set objDoc = objWord.Documents.Add
lngLastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, lngFirstCol).End(xlUp).Row
lngLastCol = Cells(lngHeaderRow, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
For lngRow = lngFirstRow To lngLastRow
    Application.StatusBar = "Processing row " & lngRow & " of " & lngLastRow
    For lngCol = lngFirstCol To lngLastCol
        objDoc.Content.InsertAfter Cells(lngHeaderRow, lngCol) & ": " & Cells(lngRow, lngCol)
        If lngCol < lngLastCol Then
            objDoc.Content.InsertParagraphAfter
        End If
    Next lngCol
    If lngRow < lngLastRow Then
        Set objRng = objDoc.Content
        objRng.Collapse Direction:=0 ' wdCollapseEnd
        objRng.InsertBreak 7 ' wdPageBreak
    End If
Next lngRow
Application.StatusBar = False
objWord.ScreenUpdating = True
objWord.Visible = True
End Sub
```

Comment: So, what have you tried changing so far?

Comment: I havent done anything with it for now im doing reserch on the web on how to do this..

Comment: Matilda, your question is a bit vague. I don't really understand what you trying to achieve. Perhaps it is best if you can take some screen shots

Comment: @Jeanno 

Why does the text change font size and stile? Can you not make it to keep it is original font size and stile like it was in excel?

https://www.dropbox.com/s/65jhb2afiadp0ia/ScreenShot_20150408143059.png?dl=0

https://www.dropbox.com/s/aktp5nwooy6hllf/ScreenShot_20150408142709.png?dl=0

Answer (score 0):

Use the Excel Macro recorder to change some sample text to the different fonts, sizes, foreground and background colors you are interested in using. The code will work the same in a MS Word document except the word text has different syntax than that found in Excel. (Google MS Word VBA change font color to get examples)

The date and numeric formats can be set using the format command. Read up on it.

Also Google MS Word VBA for moving right/down a character, word, or paragraph on how to force a new line.

The MS Word object model is harder to work with if you don't know it. I spend a lot of time testing out different code via the Immediate window. It takes a fair amount of trial and error to get everything working, due to the free form nature of a Word doc, vs. content in an Excel cell.

Good luck!